# JAXB Marshalling error

Tags: java, jaxb

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected class ja vax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType but found class javax.xml.bind.annotation. AccessType

I am getting this error when i am trying to marshal a JAXB object to XML.
Can anyone please provide any hints.

Comment: It is much easier to help you if you post your code that is doing the marshalling and the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error often occurs when the JAXB annotation class is from a different `ClassLoader` than the `ClassLoader` the JAXB implement is using.  If you are inside an OSGi enviroment make sure that you import the `javax.xml.bind.annotation` package in your `MANIFEST.MF` file.